# Dual characterization of minimal elements of a convex set

Tags: convex-optimization

In section 2.6.3 of "Convex Optimization" by Boyd and Vandenberghe (p. 55) it is stated that

> If $\lambda\succ_{K^*}0$ and $x$ minimizes $\lambda^T z$ over $z\in S$, then $x$ is minimal.

This is complemented a bit later with the assertion

> Provided the set $S$ is convex, we can say that for any minimal element $x$ there exists a non-zero $\lambda\succeq_{K^*}0$ such that $x$ minimizes $\lambda^T z$ over $z\in S$.

In my application, $K$ is the non negative orthant, $S$ is indeed convex and $\lambda^T z$ can be shown to have a unique minimum over $z\in S$ for any $\lambda\succeq 0$.

Can I say that $x$ is minimal if and only if $x$ minimizes $\lambda^T z$ over $z\in S$ for some non zero $\lambda\succeq 0$?

Comment: Please add a little bit more context. Is there any relation between $K$ and $S$? What does it mean "$x$ is minimal"?

Comment: @gerw Context is that of Boyd and Vabderberghe: $K\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is a proper cone and $K^*$ its dual. $\prec_{k^*}$ is the generalized inequality induced by $K^*$. $S\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is just any set. $x\in S$ is a minimal element of $S$ if $\nexists y\in S\mid y\preceq_K x$

Comment: Your current assumptions imply that $S$ is a singleton, since the function $z \mapsto 0^\top z$ has a unique minimizer over $S$...

Comment: @gerw. You are right, I should write $\lambda\succeq 0$ *and* $\lambda\ne 0$.  I'll edit